# I have approve button on each row and after clicking on it, it should update status as approved in database for that specific row

Tags: php

I am `displaying` a table and each row of table have a `approve` and reject `button` and after clicking on approve the status should `reflect to database as approved`.

I tried for it but after clicking on any row's approve button it will set `status` as approved for all the rows.

My PHP code is:

```
$doc_re = "select * from files where receiver='$user'";
$record = mysqli_query($conn,$doc_re);

if($record)
{
    echo " <br><center><span class='badge badge-light' style='font-size:30px; background-color:teal;color:white;padding:10px;'>RECEIVED RECORDS</span></center>";
    echo "<br><table class='table' border='3' style='background-color:rgba(2,2,2,0.7);'>";
    echo "<thead class='thead-dark' >";
    echo "<tr style='font-size:23px;'><th style='color:skyblue;'><center>TO</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>FROM</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>FILE</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>MESSAGE</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>APPROVE</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>REJECT</center></th>
          <th style='color:skyblue;'><center>STATUS</center></th></tr></thead>";

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($record,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<tr><td style='color:white; font-size:18px;'><center><strong>{$r['receiver']}</strong></center></td>
            <td style='color:white; font-size:18px;'><center><strong>{$r['sender']}</strong></center></td>
            <td style='color:white; font-size:18px;'><center><strong><a href='".$r['file']."'>{$r['file']}</a></strong></center></td>
            <td style='color:white; font-size:18px;'><center><strong>{$r['message']}</strong></center></td>
            <form method='POST'>
            <td><center>
            <button class='button button1' name='approve'  type='submit'><span>&#10003;</span></button></center></td>
            <td><center><button class='button button1' style='background-color:red;' name='reject' type='submit'><span>&#10008;</span></button></center></td>
            </form>
            <td style='color:white; font-size:18px;'><center><strong>{$r['Status']}</strong></center></td>
        </tr>";

        if(isset($_POST['approve']))
        {   
            $q1 = "update files set Status='APPROVED' where receiver='{$r['receiver']}' and sender='{$r['sender']}' ";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['reject']) )
        {
            $q2 = "update files set Status='REJECTED' where receiver='{$r['receiver']}' and sender='{$r['sender']}' ";
            $ress = mysqli_query($conn,$q2);
        }   

    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

It set's status as approved for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

The `row` which you have `selected` might be having `id`, so you can used this `id` to passed to your  query and `set` your `status` to approve or rejected like below :

```
 <td><center>
        <button class='button button1' name='approve'  type='submit'><a href="yourphp.page?status=approved&id=<?php echo $r['id'];?>"><span>&#10003;</span></a></button></center></td>
                <td><center><button class='button button1' style='background-color:red;' name='reject' type='submit'><a href="yourphp.page?status=reject&id=<?php echo $r['id'];?>"><span>&#10008;</span></a></button></center></td>
```

In above code , `yourphp.page?status=reject&id=<?php echo $r['id'];?>` this is important line ,here you are passing `status` & `id` of the row selected to some `yourphp.page`,also here i have assumed that `$r['id']` this might be `id` of your table.
Now to get value passed you can write like below :

```
$status=$_GET['status'];//will give you status
$id=$_GET['id'];//will give you id of row selected
```

Passed above value in your `query` ,like below :

```
 $q1 = "update files set Status='$status' where id=$id";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
```

Above query will update that particular row with `status` .And then after query is executed ,you can `redirect` to same page ..where your table is there .Hope this helps!

***Note*** : Also try using [**prepared statement**](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) it is safe an secure.

Comment: Could I get the status and id as input? and how and where to use the id

Comment: When you click on button using `<a href>` you can pass these values and then you need to pass that `id` in your query i.e : `where clause` as you can see in my above answer.( also there must be id of every row you retrieve from table , so used that only here, they unique for each row )

Comment: Glad to here that ,accept this answer  by clicking on tick symbol ,if it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in your query. It doesn't target the right values in the table files in your DB. It should be something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['approve'])) 
  $q = "update files set Status='APPROVED' where receiver='{$r['receiver']}' and sender='{$r['sender']}' and file='{$r['file']}'";
elseif(isset($_POST['reject']))
  $q = "update files set Status='REJECTED' where receiver='{$r['receiver']}' and sender='{$r['sender']}' and file='{$r['file']}'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
```